# Can I attend a PhD program with the intent to transfer my PhD credits to an MS and after 2 years, apply to a better university for a PhD?

Tags: phd, masters, united-states, transfer-student

I have been admitted to a PhD program at a  US university in the department of physics. The  department ranking is 100 (according to the US News ranking). In the PhD program, most of the students in physics study the fundamental principle in order to be prepared for doctoral studies. It takes around three semesters.  The  department I have been admitted to, also has an MS course.

My intention is to  transfer my PhD credits to the MS in order to gather more research experiences (2 years study) and later apply to a better university. Is it possible to manage this with my graduate supervisor? How  positive is my case? And how do you think my supervisor would respond to this?

Comment: If your intention is to get masters, then you should apply for masters.

Comment: I have admitted into PhD program

Comment: I question whether delaying your PhD by 2 years, just to (possibly) get into a higher ranked school is a good idea.  How much higher do you think you can aim?  Will this really improve your career prospects enough to offset the cost of such a delay?  You've already been admitted at a pretty good school.

Comment: If you switch to a master's, you may lose your funding or get reduced funding.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are essentially trying to transfer from one PhD program to another. When you apply to these "better" universities, you'll still be enrolled as a PhD student. Therefore [Is transferring an option for an unhappy PhD student](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/is-transferring-to-another-university-an-option-for-an-unhappy-phd-student) seems like a duplicate.